# Amazon S3 Forbidden 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Во время прохождения [13 главы Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-image_upload_in_production) столкнулся с невозможностью запустить загрузку картинок на Heroku с помощью CarrierWave, Fog и AWS S3. Каждый раз сталкиваюсь с одной и той же ошибкой:

```
2019-04-22T16:45:52.736948+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/microposts" host=anikeef-sample-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b78cf418-1931-42e0-89e5-4e92af697ed4 fwd="95.189.192.65" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1525ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2019-04-22T16:45:52.733710+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-04-22T16:45:52.733568 #8] DEBUG -- : [b78cf418-1931-42e0-89e5-4e92af697ed4]    (2.3ms)  ROLLBACK
2019-04-22T16:45:52.734152+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-04-22T16:45:52.734037 #8]  INFO -- : [b78cf418-1931-42e0-89e5-4e92af697ed4] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 511ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735688+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-22T16:45:52.735602 #8] FATAL -- : [b78cf418-1931-42e0-89e5-4e92af697ed4]
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735761+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-22T16:45:52.735692 #8] FATAL -- : [b78cf418-1931-42e0-89e5-4e92af697ed4] Excon::Error::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735764+00:00 app[web.1]: excon.error.response
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735769+00:00 app[web.1]: :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>1E231D51512F5FCD</RequestId><HostId>viioFqYRTbP07frHGpcfgl+xzN4cZqFMs37oY/dl0kHnzBNxpmoKNgjbQpxvG8kVCxaxFAxGFr0=</HostId></Error>"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735770+00:00 app[web.1]: :cookies       => [
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735772+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735774+00:00 app[web.1]: :headers       => {
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735776+00:00 app[web.1]: "Connection"       => "close"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735777+00:00 app[web.1]: "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735779+00:00 app[web.1]: "Date"             => "Mon, 22 Apr 2019 16:45:51 GMT"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735781+00:00 app[web.1]: "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735783+00:00 app[web.1]: "x-amz-id-2"       => "viioFqYRTbP07frHGpcfgl+xzN4cZqFMs37oY/dl0kHnzBNxpmoKNgjbQpxvG8kVCxaxFAxGFr0="
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735784+00:00 app[web.1]: "x-amz-request-id" => "1E231D51512F5FCD"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735786+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735788+00:00 app[web.1]: :host          => "anikeef-sample-app2.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735789+00:00 app[web.1]: :local_address => "172.17.49.150"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735791+00:00 app[web.1]: :local_port    => 43620
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735793+00:00 app[web.1]: :path          => "/uploads/micropost/picture/304/sunrise-1756274_1920.jpg"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735795+00:00 app[web.1]: :port          => 443
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735796+00:00 app[web.1]: :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735798+00:00 app[web.1]: :remote_ip     => "52.219.104.80"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735800+00:00 app[web.1]: :status        => 403
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735801+00:00 app[web.1]: :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735803+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2019-04-22T16:45:52.735927+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-22T16:45:52.735866 #8] FATAL -- : [b78cf418-1931-42e0-89e5-4e92af697ed4]
2019-04-22T16:45:52.736039+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-22T16:45:52.735966 #8] FATAL -- : [b78cf418-1931-42e0-89e5-4e92af697ed4] app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Так сейчас выглядит config/initializers/fog.rb

```rb
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider => "AWS",
      :aws_access_key_id => ENV["S3_ACCESS_KEY"],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV["S3_SECRET_KEY"],
      :region => ENV["S3_REGION"]
    }
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_directory = ENV["S3_BUCKET"]
    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end
end
```

Судя по ошибке, проблема должна исходить от AWS. Я пробовал применять разные права пользователям IAM, в том числе AmazonS3FullAccess и AdministratorAccess. 
Я пересмотрел все найденные вопросы на SO, но абсолютно ничего мне не помогло, поэтому буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: На хероку все env переменные указали? У меня что-то подобное было из-за S3_REGION

Comment: Да, регион указан, все перепроверил несколько раз

Answer (score 0):

Все наконец-то заработало только после того, как отключил пункты "Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects" и "Remove public access granted through public ACLs" в разделе S3 >  > Permissions